# Run a REQUIRE file directly?

Tags: deployment, julia

I have some work that is roughly structured like a julia package.
It has a REQUIRE file, listing its dependencies on various packages.

But it is not a registered package.
When I want to work on it, I clone a larger git repo that has a bunch of work, into my work area (Not into `~/.julia/v0.5` like  apackage would be)

I would like to execute my REQUIRE file and get all of the packages I depend on installed (into `~/.julia/v0.5`).
And have julia's package system deal with the versioning requirements.

How can I do this?

(I suspect Pkg3, when it comes to fruition will make this a long nicer)

Comment: have you tried [Pkg.resolve](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/pkg/?highlight=pkg.resolve#Base.Pkg.resolve)?

Comment: How do I pass the location of my REQUIRE file to the Pkg.resolve() function? Do I just run it, while my working directory contains a REQUIRE file?

Comment: a concise workaround is to make a new folder in `~/.julia/v0.5` and put your REQUIRE file into it, then run `Pkg.resolve()`

Comment: I suggest writing an answer

Answer (score 2):

> If unregistered packages contain a REQUIRE file at the top of their source tree, that file will be used to determine which registered packages the unregistered package depends on, and they will automatically be installed.

so a tricky workaround is to make a new folder(*fake package* e.g. `AAA`) in `~/.julia/v0.x` which contains the REQUIRE file and then run `Pkg.resolve()`.

```
- AAA                           0.0.0-             non-repo (unregistered)
```

Answer (score -1):

JULIA_PKGDIR can only hold one value. 
I find LOAD_PATH comes with most of the benefits, like `using mymodule`.

For your startup .juliarc.jl file (assuming you are onWindows):

locjpath="C:\users\oxinabox\j"
push!(LOAD_PATH, locjpath)

Comment: You post is not untrue. I do have my LOAD_PATH set in .juliarc. and it is useful. However, I don't see how that helps me with installing my REQUIRE file.